# Action bar functionality lost after returning back from second activity to the main activity's fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Application workflow scenario

1. Main Activity adds first fragment into its `FrameLayout` container. Action bar is set including implementing the `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.
2. From the first fragment a new activity is started with an `Intent`. The new activity sets its own layout file with `RecyclerView` widget.
   No action bar is set (only back navigation is provided to the parent activity which is the `Main Activity` using the manifest file).
3. When user clicks on a `CardView` item inside the `RecyclerView` widget container, second fragment of the `Main Activity` replaces the current 
   activity with the `RecyclerView` widget.
4. During fragment replacement the main activity's layout file is once again set since its `FrameLayout` container is used by fragments that 
   will follow.
5. When the second fragment is loaded the main activity (and the following fragments) action bar's  functionality is lost. The back navigation (with title) of the previous activity is visible.

I need help in figuring out how to ensure the main activity's action bar functionality (including auxiliary methods being invoked within `onCreateOptionsMenu()` of the `MainActivity`) when going back from another activity?

Thank you in advance for any valuable help.

EDIT:

MainActivity layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Activity adds first fragment into its `FrameLayout` container:

```
BaseFragment firstFragment = new BaseFragment();

         // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, firstFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
```

`onCreateOptionsMenu()` of the MainActivity:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    // Add the shopping cart menu item onto action bar.
    MenuItem cartItem = menu.findItem(R.id.ab_cartView);

    // Add the search view menu item onto action bar and hide it until ProductListFragment
    MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    search.setVisible(false);

    // Check whether the DB table has entries - if true, then display the shopping cart icon.
    if (db.getActiveItemsCount() > 0)
        cartItem.setVisible(true);
    else
        cartItem.setVisible(false);

    MenuItemCompat.setActionView(cartItem, R.layout.action_bar_notification_icon);
    ab_cartView = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(cartItem);

    ab_cartView_notification = (TextView) ab_cartView.findViewById(R.id.ab_cartView_items_notification);

    // Update list items count label of ab_cartView_notification
    updateListItemsCount();
}
```

New activity is started with an `Intent` from the `firstFragment`:

```
Intent displayListSelectionIntent = new  
Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), ListSelectionActivity.class);

// Add data about current status to the intent
displayListSelectionIntent.putExtra("ListStatus_Active", true);
startActivity(displayListSelectionIntent);
```

New activity's (`ListSelectionActivity`) layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#e2e6fb" >

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/cardList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

listener interface for the `ListSelectionAdapter` and method for replacing `ListSelectionActivity` by the second fragment of the main activity:

```
// Instantiate click listener interface for the ListSelectionAdapter
ListSelectionAdapter.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new    ListSelectionAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
      replaceFragment (new CategoryFragment());
   }
};
```

`replaceFragment()`:

```
private void replaceFragment(CategoryFragment categoryFragment) {
    String backStateName = categoryFragment.getClass().getName();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate (backStateName, 0);
    // IF fragment not in back stack, create it
    if (!fragmentPopped) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, categoryFragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: What about sharing essential parts of your code?

Comment: @joaquin - Please, check out my edited question with relevant code. Thanks.